# How to call a custom action from a UI in Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to add a delay to an installer. The reason for this is the installer must run a third party driver, but windows does not give "the device is ready to use" notification in time.

This leads to issues for the software as the version to be installed is determined by the device the driver is used for.

What I would like to do is generate a UI that will count down from say 10 to 1 before allowing the user to then proceed.

I have searched through documentation but haven't found anything in Wix that is capable of dong this.

Is this possible in Wix or how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is that you do a publish event from the dialog, as in this tutorial:

http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/control-your-controls

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this driver package is a prerequisite to installing your MSI. Therefore I'd create a burn bootstrapper bundle to install it before installing your MSI.  I'd have to know more about this package but I suspect the thing to do is create a custom EXE to encapsulate the process and then wait up to 10 seconds while confirming the package is fully committed.  Then it can return and burn will carry on to your MSI installation.

You shouldn't be installing drivers (or making any configuration changes to the machine) during the UI phase of your MSI.

Comment: Hi Christopher, it isn't a prerequisite every time, it is a dongle that is used if the end user requires a hardware license, we support another type of hardware license with a separate driver so I can't create a burn bootstrapper as you had suggested. I was going to start with just adding a custom action that ran a sleep command when the user hit the corresponding dialog button, but haven't figured out how to get this to run at the right time yet.

Comment: Can you defer this to application runtime?

Comment: No as the driver needs to be installed to read the license to install our software. I am picking up from another developer so still trying to map out how the package is put together.  I am still testing but haven't managed to call my UI at the right time (i.e if the key has not been validated).

Comment: I'm trying to get you to reconsider that requirement.  DRM is best handled in an application not in an installer.  An MSI can easily be transformed to bypass this check and install anyways.